# Запрос со сравнением двух столбцов в MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы t1 и t2.

**t1**

```
| user_id | nick | message | 
|    -    |user_1|  text   |
|    -    |user_2|  text   |
```

**t2**

```
 | user_id | nick | 
 |    23   |user_1|
 |    45   |user_2|
```

Какой сформировать запрос, чтобы заполнить столбец user_id в t1, используя данные t2? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Вроде так

```
update t1 
inner join t2 on
    t1.nick = t2.nick
set t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```